# Authentication is disabled in OpenSearch result source on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, opensearch

I have currently encountered a problem with SharePoint Online. 
I'm trying to configure an OpenSearch result source.

- On SharePoint 2013, I can configure the authentication.
- On SharePoint Online, the inputs are disabled and locked on anonymous.

Is there a way to enable the other authentification methods ?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I was told by O365 support that this is disabled by design, which I was not pleased with.  I suggest that you too start a ticket with them and express your eventual displeasure.

Federated search with a hybrid environment may solve the problem, but I'm not hopeful that if I search from the cloud I'll see the same results that I will see if I search from the on-prem farm.